# Is it safe to perform a firmware upgrade on a Canon 60D camera?

Tags: upgrade, firmware

How safe is it to perform a firmware upgrade on a camera? I know what firmware upgrade is and what advantages/possible disadvantages it brings, I'm just specifically asking how *safe* or *unsafe* it is to perform one.

Can something go wrong? What should I double-check before performing an upgrade?

Comment: Are you talking about official upgrades, or unofficial ones?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the official upgrades.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I trust Canon is sane enough and tests all official firmware upgrades not to brick your camera. As long as you follow the guide that comes with the firmware (instructions like "don't remove battery during upgrade") you should be completely safe.